# How to change LED trigger?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-device-driver, led

I have register in BSP's the LED:

```
static struct gpio_led ic_leds[] = {
        {
                .name                   = "led1:green",
                .gpio                   = USER_LED,
                .default_trigger        = "heartbeat",
                .active_low             = 1,
        },
};

static struct gpio_led_platform_data ic_led_info = {
        .num_leds       = ARRAY_SIZE(ic_leds),
        .leds           = ic_leds,
};

static struct platform_device ic_leds_device = {
        .name   = "leds-gpio",
        .id     = -1,
        .dev    = {
                .platform_data = &ic_led_info,
        },
};

static void __init ic_add_device_leds(void)
{
        platform_device_register(&ic_leds_device);
}
```

How can I change the trigger in run time? I know that it's possible with sysfs, but maybe exist another way?

Answer (score 5):

```
echo "thetriggeryouwant" > /sys/class/leds/someled/trigger
```

where `thetriggeryouwant` is for example `phy0rx` and `someled` is the name of the led you want to change the trigger for.

---

To get all available triggers for that led, you can `cat` the file:

```
cat /sys/class/leds/someled/trigger
```

gives for example:

> `[none] timer oneshot mtd nand-disk heartbeat backlight gpio cpu cpu0 cpu1 activity default-on 2188000.ethernet-2:00:link 2188000.ethernet-2:00:100Mbps 2188000.ethernet-2:00:10Mbps`

where the item in brackets (`[none]`) denotes the current trigger.